# Chat user cards can't handle hundreds of badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Chat user card layouts can't handle the situation where a user has a double-digit number of gold badges and triple-digit numbers of silver and bronze badges (or any number of badges totaling eight digits).

In other words, "Jeff Atwood: Unsupported!"

[image: bronze badge count pushed to next line]

Comment: Your pixel-precise paint lines are awesome.

Comment: Simple solution: Downvote Jeff below 100k. Drop me a line when you're done, I'll [status-completed] this question then.

Comment: TAKE THAT, BENEVOLENT DICTATOR FOR LIFE

Comment: (please don't ban me)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are now handled a bit more cleanly by using ellipsis when the counts run over rather than the nasty layout breaks.